# Block direct download of image in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image, paperclip

Now doing Image gallery in rails. I want to block the direct access of downloading image from web page.How do this thing?. I am using paperclip gem to upload image. Please Help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will need to have access to the image in order to display it; at some point something on the browser will have direct access to the image.

You can obfuscate how the image is retrieved, but that's basically the best you can do. You might be able to play minor games with the referrer.

Don't disable right-click; that's irritating.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for a login system, I assume.  Make sure the image is served by a controller, not by nginx, or whatever is serving your statics.  Given that you're using Paperclip, I assume this is already the case.  So really you just need to check for a logged in user inside the controller, and return a 403 response or something if the user isn't logged in.